# 20x4 LCD Error. 8 black boxes to the left on row 3 and 4

Tags: lcd

20x4 I2C conected LCD. 8 black boxes to the left on row 3 and 4.
What could the problem be?

[image: see picture]

Comment: Add the (relevant) code

Comment: What Arduino? Due or Mega? My guess is that your i2c wires are too long and/or there is a timing issue. Is this the code? https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C/blob/master/examples/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.pde

Comment: the picture does not show black boxes ... they look white or light blue to me

Comment: @MikaelPatel. im running on a Mega 2560. Yes it is that code. but i have tried diffrent code. same everytime. I dont have shorter Wires, but i have tested extended them to over 100 cm. No diffrence at all to my 20 cm cables. So mayby the length of the cables are not the issue? Mayby its just a bad lcd?

Comment: Ok so it is not the wire length. It is the first 8 characters per line and these do not map to the sketch. Or have you changed the sketch? Please add the sketch you are running.

Comment: @MiaelPatel  ok my latest code has the same problem as the LiquidCrystal_I2C example code. i wrote to the lcd is a simple calculator. Here is that code. (Im sorry the coments are in swedish. https://create.arduino.cc/editor/halt1/a2917809-ce6d-4dc7-8962-28e274b8fe9b/preview